# Merging three linestring tables into one new table view

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have three tables in a PostGIS database and I want to create a table view merging the features from the three tables into one, by using PostgreSQL.
The three tables are containing three different kinds of roads, hence I want the view to specify the type of road in a new column.

The three tables do all contain a geometry column (linestrings)

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Coding questions are expected to contain code. By including your SQL, you provide the names of the tables and columns needed for the answer.

Comment: @Vince Okay, sorry - I will remember that next time.

Comment: @kwiwe to get your question re-opened you can [edit] it to add any code etc. which could attract more answers, but could also mean it helps other users with similar questions in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new fields in the view definition:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_roads as
SELECT r1.id,
    r1.geometry,
    1 as road_type,
    'type1' as road_type2
FROM roads_1 r1
UNION ALL
SELECT r2.id,
    r2.geometry,
    2 as road_type,
    'type2' as road_type2
FROM roads_2 r2
UNION ALL
SELECT r3.id,
    r3.geometry,
    3 as road_type,
    'type3' as road_type2
FROM roads_3 r3;
```

Comment: @JHG Thank you so much :-)! Works excellent!
If i want to merge all the line pieces in r1, r2 and r3 before I create v_roads view, what can I do then?

Comment: @kwiwe you can do it in the view definition (read on st_collect or st_union), but it is likely a bad idea because it would be recomputed every time you query the view. It will be more efficient to create a new table or a materialized view that you refresh only when the data changes. Now these are different questions that should be asked in new posts

Comment: @JHG Okay thanks! - i am quite new in this forum.
I think will create a new table instead. If I want to create a new unique ID instead of using the existing ones, how do I do this?

Comment: add an `Identity` column (or the old `serial`)